# How do I able load a multiple groovy file from single Jenkins file run as parallel

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

```
@Library(xxxxxxx) _
@Library(xxxxxxx) _

properties([
    parameters([
        choice(choices: ['failover', 'revert'], description: 'choose whether to failover or revert failover', name: 'ACTION'),      
        choice(choices: ['qa', 'prod'], description: 'choose the environment to failover or revert failover', name: 'ENVIRONMENT')
    ])
])

timestamps { 
    node {
        try {
            parallel {
                dir("Jenkinsfiles") {
                    stage('Initiate REDIS Failover'){
                        def example = load("web.groovy")
                    }
                    stage('Initiate RDS Failover'){
                        def example = load("Common.groovy")
                    }
                    stage('Initiate WEB Failover'){
                        def example = load("rds.groovy")
                    }
                }
            }
        finally {
            cleanWs()
        }
    }
}
```

Above is Jenkinsfile which is pointed to the as an SCM in Jenkins pipeline Job.

I want to run those in the Jenkinsfiles directory web.groovy, Common.groovy file. Those files from the main Jenkinsfile as parallel in stage wise.